# Unable to update other table rows other than 1st created

Tags: laravel

I have this problem while creating application in Laravel. Users need to be able to edit posts but when click on edit button it updates only very first post created. Cant access other posts. How can i make that it updates that exact post i pressed button on. What could be the problem here?

edit.blade.php

```
<form action="/profile/{{ $post->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')
...edit form here...
```

web.php

```
Route::patch('/profile/{post}', 'PostsController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

PostsController.php

```
public function update(Post $post)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'category' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image',
        ]);
        $post->update($data);
        return redirect("/profile/".auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

Post model
namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your controller, you are only validating the request not updating the post.

Comment: just forgot to add the line. But it was there previosely

Comment: is the route model binding works as expected?

Comment: i need to pass in correct post id to function. How do i do it with possibly less changes to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you have to find it first 
like this

```
 $post = Post::find($post->id);
 $post->update($data);
```

Comment: it doesnt help. i inserted my current model in post too